# SQL - Update a table using a field of another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to execute the following update query:

```
UPDATE Commodities 
INNER JOIN UniqueCountries 
     ON Commodities.wbCode = UniqueCountries.wbCode 
SET Idenb = UniqueCountries.wbName||yr
```

The query is clearly wrong, as it doesnt work. How can I fix it?

---

The query is supposed to update column `IdenB` with the concatenated value of `wbName` and `yr` (`wbName||yr`). However, `wbName` is on another table called `UniqueCountries`, which is why I tried to perform an Inner Join.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see any indication [in the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) that `FROM` or `JOIN`  are supported in `UPDATE` statements.

Maybe you could try a correlated sub query if not.

```
UPDATE Commodities  
SET Idenb = (SELECT UniqueCountries.wbName||yr 
             FROM UniqueCountries 
             WHERE Commodities.wbCode = UniqueCountries.wbCode)
```